# How to remove Title and white spaces from a page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I managed to remove the title of a page now I've white spaces there how do I remove it. I used the following css in the content editor webpart to remove the title.

```
<style>

.ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;}
</style>
```

Comment: #DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea{Display:none !Important;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the "ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"-box up by using CSS. 
I used "top" to move the box vertically.

```
<style>
.ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;}
.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {position: relative;
    top: -50px;}
</style>
```

Additionally you can move the box horizontally by adding e. g. "left: -30px;" into the bracket

Comment: Hi Steff, It worked please see the code may i ask how to get rid of the the image and

Comment: or can you point me somewhere to get the details of the CSS

Comment: Hello Rinu. The "trick" how I find out about elements name is:
Use Firefox and get the Add-On called "Firebug".
If u are on any Site and press F12, there is a function in the ADD-on (icon with a window and mouse on) that you can get details of the code by Mouseover. There you can also see the element names like ".ms-..." and if you are adding them to your CSS you can change them however you want :)

Comment: See this step here starting at 2:15 for how to use Firebug: https://youtu.be/igguTa6oZeI?t=2m11s
It works same on SharePoint. Somehow the Add-On only works properly on Mozilla Firefox. If you can't install it in your company, you might get a portable version of Firefox (I also got a portable one). Greetings ;)

Answer (score 2):

No need for `!important` [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) hacks

After

```
#pageTitle {
   display:none
}
```

there is whitespace because the `contentRow` is pushed down by the whole DIV row (including Logo)

[image]

You could push the page content only up with:

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain{
    margin-top:-64px;
}
```

But note that other UI elements (like the Noticification area in the top right of the page **content**) will also move 64 pixels up...

To counter that:

```
#notificationArea{
    margin-top:64px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: some how i cant get it to work please see the script i have used may be am doing something wrong <style>
.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
.#pageTitle {
   display:none
}
.ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;}
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain{
    margin-top:-64px;
}
</style>

Comment: That is not the lines of code I wrote. Use something like [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) to live edit CSS against your SP page